# full width background image inside set width div

Tags: css, wordpress, background-image, fullscreen

Hoping you can help with my query.
I'm in the process of building a WP blog within a hand coded website and having issues due to the css in WP being complicated. 
Here's the page
http://www.carehomesderby.co.uk/news/
I want to span the menu nav and footer the full width of the browser, keeping the content central
I've tried setting the ul width to 3000px (for example) but it adds on about 30px to the RHS. I can't separate the menu nav as it's within the header.php in WP. 
Styles are being pulled through for the same element in several places so I'm having difficulty in determining what's what. 
Many thanks in advance

Comment: It's hard to answer your question when the web site is actively being changed as I'm writing... :)

Comment: Sorry Anders! I have stopped changing. Thank you for taking the time to look. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have see your page
For footer if you want it to cover full page then just remove the role from footer tag

```
<footer id="colophon" style="width:100%;" role="contentinfo">
```

just remove the contentinfo from the role attribute.

just remove the contentinfo from the role attribute.

For Navigation : you need to couple of thing, I am here giving you an idea

1. Remove the max-width for site class

   `.site
       {
       /*max-width: 68.5714rem;*/
       }`
2. remove width 950px value from div tag

   `<div id="page" class="hfeed site" style="padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px;">`

what it will do is, Your navigation and page will acquire entire page then just set content wherever you want other than navigation.

Comment: Surely I mark it as the answer when it's fixed? Help on the nav would be appreciated :) I've tried clicking the 'useful' link next to your answer but I can't as I haven't enough reps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add:

```
position:absolute;
left:0px;
```

on line 1479.

And put the navigation buttons in a new div inside the nav bar. For example:

```
<div class="nav-menu">
        <div class="nav-button">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Facilities</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Respite Care</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Day Care</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>

        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
```

and then center the buttons.